# Why default security settings in Spring authorization server configure CSRF to ignore OIDC endpoints?

Tags: spring-security, openid-connect, csrf, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I configured CSRF prevention for my auth server and noticed that requests for endpoint `oauth2/authorize` are not mathched in `CsrfFilter`, therefore CSRF token is not required for OAuth2 endpoints (as well as `oauth/token`, `oauth/introspect` etc)

I applied default security when configuring `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
```

which is implemented as follows:

```java
public static void applyDefaultSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer =
         new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();
   RequestMatcher endpointsMatcher = authorizationServerConfigurer
         .getEndpointsMatcher();

   http
      .securityMatcher(endpointsMatcher)
      .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
         authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
      )
**      .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(endpointsMatcher))
**      .apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);
}
```

My question is, why this is the default setting for CSRF in auth server? Are we safe from CSRF attacks in these endpoints and if yes, can you explain why?

Comment: To use CSRF, you need the CSRF token. I see no way to get the CSRF token in the OAuth2 client. The fronend would need to pass the CSRF token to the client.

Comment: See also this old blog: https://spring.io/blog/2011/11/30/cross-site-request-forgery-and-oauth2

Answer (score 2):

The OpenID Connect spec defines the `state` parameter which is used to avoid CSRF attacks during the authentication/authorization process. For other scenarios, like when you send a `Bearer` token, CSRF protection is also not needed since you are not (theoretically) sending session cookies (which are included automatically by browsers)